# Convert cURL from PHP to ruby code

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, ruby, curl

I am trying to create a form for the user to buy product from my Ruby on Rails website by using their "Scratch Card for Mobile Phones".

The problem is that the service only provides Module code for PHP. So I have to convert it to Ruby to put into my website. Here are the codes I want to convert to Ruby:

```
$post_field = 'xyz=123&abc=456';

$api_url = "https://www.nganluong.vn/mobile_card.api.post.v2.php"; 

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$api_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING , 'UTF-8'); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_field); 
$result = curl_exec($ch);
$status = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE); 
$error = curl_error($ch);
```

I have tried to convert them to Ruby code but always got confused. Can anyone help me convert these codes into working Ruby codes? Thanks in advance!

Here is my silly code so far:

```
RestClient.post($api_url, $post_field, "Content-Type" => "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
```

Basically all that I need is a ruby version of the php curl code. I'm a newbie, not an experienced programmer, so please help.

Comment: So post what you've got so far...

Comment: I've updated my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
require 'rest-client'
require 'rack'

post_query = 'xyz=123&abc=456'
api_url = "https://www.nganluong.vn/mobile_card.api.post.v2.php"

query_hash = Rack::Utils.parse_nested_query(post_query)

begin
  response = RestClient.post api_url, :params => query_hash
  print response.code
  print response.body
rescue Exception => e
  print e.message
end
```

Comment: Thank you very much! How a bout $result = curl_exec($ch);? This is very important, because I need to get the vallue of $result .

Answer (score 1):

All the code is doing is sending a payload `xyz=123&abc=456` through a POST request to a specified URL.

You might use e.g. the [curb](https://github.com/taf2/curb) gem for this:

```
response = Curl.post("https://www.nganluong.vn/mobile_card.api.post.v2.php", {:xyz => 123, :abc => 456})
result = response.body_str
status = response.status
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Your answer helped me understand a lot.